# How to remove ad customizer data using AdWords Script?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have just successfully completed Google AdWords customizer script tutorial and it will succesfully parse the file and create/update the data within the business data. However, I cannot find any documentation on how to remove a row using a script.

So, I was wondering if there was a way to remove a row from my customizer data feed using a script? If you follow the bulk upload instructions from the Manage ads and feeds documentation you just create a new column called 'Action' and then put 'Remove' in the row you want removed. Then when you upload the file it removes the row. However if you follow these instructions and use a script to dynamically update the feed the row will not be removed.

Or is there a way to replace all values within the data feed from a script?

I will be happy with either solution or just the documentation with the correct syntax on how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance,
Stephen

Links:
Ad Customizer:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/customizer

Manage ads and feeds in "Business data":
https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6072708?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deep within the bowels of the AdWords documentation lies a section that talks about [AdWordsApp.AdCustomizerItem](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_adcustomizeritem)

So to answer my own question the correct syntax for deleting an item/row within a data source/feed is: AdCustomizerItem[.remove()](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_adcustomizeritem#remove_0)